# Harmonic conjugate of $\ln|z|$ in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> How I prove that $u(z)=\ln |z|$ has no harmonic conjugate in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ ?

I found from C-R equation that $v(z)=\arctan(y/x)$ , which is defined in  $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ . So why it is not a harmonic conjugate of $u$ ?

Comment: wouldn't $v(z)$ only be defined in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ \Re(z)=0  \}$? That might be why, although I'm not sure.

Comment: It's **not** defined on all of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @Daniel , Why ? It is not continuous on non-positive real axis.

Comment: Does there exists any rule to show that $v$ is not a harmonic conjugate of $u$ ?

Comment: It's **locally** a harmonic conjugate of $u$, on every domain where it can be continuously defined. But it cannot be globally defined continuously. Writing $\arctan \frac{y}{x}$, you have the function not defined on $\{z:\operatorname{Re}z=0\}$, but on both, the left and the right half planes, you can choose a branch of $\arctan$. You can make the choices so that the branches on the left and the right half-plane fit continuously together along either the upper or the lower imaginary half-axis, but you cannot choose branches so that they fit continuously together on both parts of the half-axis.

Comment: Obviously $\arctan (y/x)$ is not defined on the $y$-axis,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose a harmonic function $u \colon \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ has a (global) harmonic conjugate $v$. Then $f \colon \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $f(z) = u(z) + iv(z)$ is holomorphic, and therefore

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} f'(z)\,dz = 0.$$

Now, for holomorphic $f = u + i v$ we have

$$f'(z) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(z) + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x},$$

and with the Cauchy-Riemann equations, that becomes

$$f'(z) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(z) - i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(z).$$

Now, for $u(z) = \ln \lvert z\rvert$, we find

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x+iy) = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\quad\text{ and }\quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x+iy) = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2},$$

and thus

$$f'(z)\,dz = \frac{\overline{z}\,dz}{\lvert z\rvert^2} = \frac{dz}{z},$$

and it is well-known that

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi i \neq 0.$$

Comment: A little confusion. Here $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$. So $f'$ has a singularity (at $z=0$) in $|z|=1$. So how $\int_{|z|=1} f'(z) \,dz=0$ ?

Comment: It's because $f'$ is a derivative. For every path of integration $\gamma \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, we have $$\int_\gamma f'(z)\,dz = \int_a^b f'(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)\,dt = \int_a^b (f\circ\gamma)'(t)\,dt = f(\gamma(b)) - f(\gamma(a))$$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. So if $\gamma$ is a closed path ($\gamma(a) = \gamma(b)$), the integral is $0$. The unit circle is a closed path.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\log z = \ln|z| + i\text { arg }z$ denote the principal value logarithm, which is holomorphic on $U =\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0].$ Suppose $\ln |z| + iv(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}.$ Then on $U,$ $\log z - (\ln |z| + iv(z))$ is holomorphic and purely imaginary. By the open mapping theorem, or the CR equations, this function is constant on $U.$ This implies $\ln |z| + iv(z)$  has the same jump discontinuity problem that $\log z$ has at every point on the negative real axis. It follows that $\ln |z| + iv(z)$ is not holomorphic on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\},$ contradiction.

Comment: I don't know why this is underrated.  I like this as we skip computation and it gives much more insight.

Comment: @CloudJR Thank you for your comment.