# How to find the harmonic conjugate of $v(x,y)=\log((x-1)^2 +(y-2)^2)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

So I have found out $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{2x-2}{(x-1)^2 +(y-2)^2},\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \frac{2y-4}{(x-1)^2 +(y-2)^2}.$$

Using the Cauchy Riemann equations, I find: 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{2y-4}{(x-1)^2 +(y-2)^2},\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{2-2x}{(x-1)^2 +(y-2)^2}.$$

Then I integrate either one of $\partial u/\partial x$ or $\partial u/\partial y$ to then differentiate with respect to the other variable I just integrated with. However, when I integrate $\partial u/\partial x$ or $\partial u/\partial y$, I get two different functions: $2\arctan\frac{(x-1)}{(y-2)} + g(y)$ and $-2\arctan\frac{(y-2)}{(x-1)} + g(x)$, respectively.

What am I doing wrong? Can you have multiple harmonic conjuguates?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to find an harmonic conjugate of $v$ since there is none. That is, there is no function $u\colon\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1+2i\}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ which is an harmonic conjugate of $v$. You will find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022513/harmonic-conjugate-of-lnz-in-mathbb-c-setminus-0).

Comment: I know $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ is equal to $-\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, as you see my numerator for $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ differs but a negative one to my numerator for $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. I also don't understand how $u\colon\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1+2i\}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ relates to my function $v(x,y)$.

Comment: I have deleted my first sentence. On the other hand, I thought that your problem was to find an harmonic conjugate $u$ of $v$. Am I wrong?

Comment: No you are right, the question I was given was find the harmonic conjugate of $v(x,y)=\log((x-1)^2 +(y-2)^2)$?. I know a harmonic conjugate exists as it is a harmonic function, as I check that already.

Comment: No. The fact that $v$ is harmonic only assures that a harmonic conjugate exists *localy*. But your function is a standard example of function without a *global* harmonic conjugate.

Comment: What does locally and globally mean in this context? And does this mean that $v(x,y)$ has no harmonic conjugate?

Comment: For each $(x,y)\in D_v$ there is an open ball $B$ centered at that point such that $v|_B$ has a harmonic conjugate; that's the meaning of the fact that *locally* $v$ has a harmonic conjugate. However, there is no harmonic conjugate of $v$ whose domain is $D_v$; that's what it means that there is no harmonic conjugate *globally*.

Comment: I still don't understand the concept of locally and globally fully, I have not been taught about global and local harmonic conjugates. Are you basically saying there is no general harmonic function, but there can be specific point ones? e.g. 1+2i etc.

Comment: Actually, $1+2i$ is a bad choice, since $1+2i$ is the only point outside the domain of $v$. There is no global harmonic conjugate of $v$, but there is one near **every** point of its domain.

Comment: So if I exclude $1+2i$, can I find a function that is a harmonic conjugate of $v(x,y)$? I can't visualise or conceptualise the meaning of how there is a harmonic conjugate never every point of its domain.

Comment: I have no more ways of telling you that $v$ has no harmonic conjugate. I'm off.

Comment: Thank you for your time Jose! I really appreciate it.